# Setting radiobuttons to default

Tags: c#, radio-button, default, tablelayoutpanel

I'm using c# in Visual Studio 2010. I have a tablelayoutpanel with 8 rows and each row has 3 radiobuttons. The options are Available, Unavailable and Not Reviewed. I want to make it so as soon as the page is opened, the all 'Not Reviewed' radiobuttons are set to default. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the RadioButton.Checked property to True.